# Lazy loader on resource bitmap property

Tags: c#, winforms, resources

I got some bitmaps which are wrapped on a windows resources. The matter is that each time I access the Resources property, the  `ResourceManager.GetObject()` will always create a new instance of the bitmap and, of course, at the end I got some memory issues.

```
// Auto-generated code 
class Resources { 
        internal static System.Drawing.Bitmap IconMan16 {
            get {
                object obj = ResourceManager.GetObject("IconMan16 ", resourceCulture);
                return ((System.Drawing.Bitmap)(obj));
            }
        }
}
```

As if this class Resources is used too many times in my application, I can't change the way I called it.

**Is there any way (without editing the auto-generated file) to prevent the resource to create a new instance each time I asked for a property ?**  Something like :

```
// Auto-generated code 
class Resources {

        private static  System.Drawing.Bitmap iconMan16Cache  ; 

        internal static System.Drawing.Bitmap IconMan16 {
            get {

                return iconMan16Cache ? (iconMan16Cache = ((System.Drawing.Bitmap)(ResourceManager.GetObject("IconMan16 ", resourceCulture))));  // Thread-safety is not the question
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: The new obj Object not in a global scope, so whenever the code completes execution aumatically object will be released. Garbage collector will collects and cleans the memory. So this object is not a memory issue If I'm correct. So can you check and confirm once.

Comment: Ty for your answer. Actually you're right when you're saying that as the new bitmap is not referenced anywhere I will be actually GCed. On the other hand, Bitmap are using unmanaged object so the correct way to free it is always to call Dispose(). That's what I can't do here